# Host-only mode in VMware

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have created Windows 10 VM and my NIC card is set to host-only mode. My problem is that from host system I can see virtual machine (by ping tool) but from virtual machine I cant't see host system.

Answer (score 0):

I think your setup is correct.  I have VMware Workstation V17 here.

Please see:

[VMware Host Only](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/17/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-93BDF7F1-D2E4-42CE-80EA-4E305337D2FC.html#GUID-93BDF7F1-D2E4-42CE-80EA-4E305337D2FC)

Host Only is supposed to be isolated and connect only between guest and host.  The guest cannot connect with other machines - just the host.

Host Only is on VMnet1.   You can use the VMware Network Editor (Edit, Virtual Network Editor) to reset Host Only (VMnet1) and test. You can accomplish the same thing by uninstalling VMware, restart, and reinstalling VMware.

If you want a normal working connection, use NAT Networking (or possibly Bridged Networking).

Comment: That page only says that host-only mode is "useful for" setting up an isolated network; it does not say that host-only mode is always necessarily isolated. (Moreover, isolated from what exactly? It's already isolated from outside, so it can't also be isolated *from the host,* as then it would become completely non-functional...)

Comment: I took the Guest Host connection to be known, but I did clarify my post to say so in words.  Thanks.